# Não consigo instalar o pacote stringi no CentOS

Tags: r

Eu estou tentando instalar o pacote `stringi` num cluster que roda CentOS 7, mas estou falhando miseravelvente. O erro que ocorre está abaixo:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHKpp7q/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("stringi") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

[Já fiz esta pergunta no SO original e obtive um comentário nela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965895/stringi-package-wont-install-in-centos), mas minha ignorância no Linux não permitiu que eu entendesse o que preciso fazer. Sei que tem algo a ver com `libstdc++.so.6`, mas não consigo ir mais adiante do que isto.

Os detalhes da sessão do `R` onde tentei instalar o pacote estão abaixo.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: Você já tentou algo deste tipo? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16620942/3297472

Comment: Acabei de tentar. Não funcionou. Continuo recebendo a mesma mensagem de erro que coloquei na pergunta acima, mesmo tendo rodado `sudo yum install libstdc++*`.

Comment: Acho que isso pode resolver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20357035/3297472

Comment: Não. Nada funcionou. Eu inclusive instalei todos os pacotes com gcc que existem no yum, setei o path das libraries como neste link e, mesmo assim,  continuo recebendo o mesmo erro. O engraçado é que não tenho este problema no Ubuntu ou no macOS (mesmo instalando a versão source do pacote). Só o CentOS que não quer colaborar comigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Descobri o problema. Ao rodar

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

recebo o output

```
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_TM_1
```

Ou seja, eu não tenho o `CXXABI_1.3.8` instalado no cluster. Quando fui investigar a razão disso, descobri que poderia ser a minha versão do `gcc` que estivesse desatualizada. Fui checar qual versão eu tinha e bingo:

```
$ gcc -v
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
```

Agora era só questão de instalar o `gcc 4.9.x`. Para fazer isto no CentOS, basta rodar

```
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-gfortran
$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

Os dois primeiros comandos instalam os compiladores C, C++ e Fortran. O terceiro diz para o sistema operacional utilizar o `gcc 4.9.x` como compilador padrão. Assim, quando eu checo qual versão do `gcc` está ativa no cluster, obtenho o seguinte:

```
$ gcc -v
gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC)
```

Isto feito, bastou entrar o `R`, executar `install.packages("stringi")` e instalar o pacote normalmente.

Em resumo, meu problema era a versão do `gcc` instalada na máquina. Até onde apurei, o `stringi` exige que seja a versão 4.9.x. A versão 4.8.x, mais antiga, não funcionou, assim como a 5.3.0 também não serviu.